# Check n consecutive rows of a particular column if they are all greater than a fixed threshold

Tags: python, pandas

Top 20 rows of my dataframe looks like this:

```
 date            colA   colB    colC 
35  2020-04-22  500000  26893   500000  
36  2020-04-23  500000  26893   500000  
37  2020-04-24  500000  26893   500000  
38  2020-04-25  500000  65586   500000  
39  2020-04-26  500000  65586   500000  
40  2020-04-27  500000  65586   500000  
41  2020-04-28  500000  28586   500000  
42  2020-04-29  500000  28586   500000  
43  2020-04-30  500000  28586   500000  
44  2020-05-01  500000  28586   500000  
45  2020-05-02  500000  28586   500000
46  2020-05-03  500000  28586   500000  
47  2020-05-04  500000  28586   500000  
48  2020-05-05  500000  28586   500000  
49  2020-05-06  500000  28586   500000  
50  2020-05-07  500000  28586   500000  
51  2020-05-08  500000  28586   500000  
52  2020-05-09  500000  28586   500000  
53  2020-05-10  500000  28586   500000  
54  2020-05-11  500000  28586   500000
```

I want to check if in `colB` 25 consecutive rows have values greater than `30000`. If it is, then I return the first `date` with which we have started or else we return the date which has its next consecutive 25 rows greater than the threshold.

I have approached the problem by checking:

```
k = df[df['colB']>30000]
str(k.iloc[0].date.date())
```

But this only returns the first date of the ones which are only more than `30000` which includes skipping the rows and keeping the ones satisfying. I do not intend to skip the rows. I need each and every row to be more than the threshold and take the first `date` that satisfies the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rolling and shift:

```
df['isStart'] = df['colB'].rolling(25).agg(lambda x: np.all(x>3000)).shift(-24)
df['isStart'] = df['isStart'].astype(bool)
df.loc[df['isStart'], 'date']
```

Comment: Your solution is almost correct! `df_co.loc[df_co['isStart'], 'date']` is giving me some error. But when I check the `df` it is correctly putting 1 in `isStart`  column on the right `date`. The error I am getting is very long it says something like `'None of [35    0.0\n36    0.0\n37    0.0\n38    0.0\n39    0.0\n40    0.0\n41    0.0\n42    0.0\n43    0.0\n44    0.0\n45    0.0\n46    0.0\n47 ... isStart, Length: 63, dtype: float64] are in the [index]' `

Comment: It is because isStart is float, sorry! Can you try now?

Comment: The best solution I can ever expect! Thank you so much Bruno! :)